# JSON Parser recommendation: Is there a JSON Parser which maintains order?

Tags: java, json, parsing, json-simple

I know a JSON that maintains order is no longer JSON, but this is a requirement in some use and throw code. I have read other hacks like replacing HashMap with LinkedHashMap in the JSONObject.java file. I was wondering if there is a parser which does this without any modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a streaming JSON parser, e.g. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), which will deliver the tags as it finds it. Of course that means that you might have to change your program logic to process the JSON elements on the fly.